# Facebook Api Like with Acess token

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I am using Facebook SDK with HTC Sense Token, i saw some sites that with that token can like pictures and post to anyone wall with it, without any login.
so i want to do that requests without user auth just with the token
doing like this with the token i want to send requests without use a app(using the htc sense token)

i was trying like this but it needs configure a app and i dont want to use it coz the token will not work.

```
`$facebook->setAccessToken('mytoken');
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
array(
'link' => 'www.example.com',
'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
));
print_r($ret_obj);`
```

Comment: You can not use the API to act on behalf of a user without having them login to your app and grant it appropriate permissions first.

Comment: but i am using htc sense check this site -> http://official-liker.net/token.php

Comment: Without knowing the id of the app that the token belongs to, you can not use the token to post. You could look up the app id using Facebook’s debug tool – but you should really rather create your own app, because that app in question asks for all kinds of permissions, and will probably do something shady with them in your name. You should not trust sites like this one bit, there is a very high chance this is some kind of spam/scam app.

Comment: well, having in mind that i have the id, but i dont have the app secret what i cna do?

 App ID 41158896424 : HTC Sense

Comment: You don’t need the app secret to make a post (unless it is enabled in the app’s security settings) – but again: _Create your own app!_ Using this app will only be harmful – it asks for every permission there is, and there is no good reason to do this, unless the app’s operator has something shady in mind. Even the title hints at that – I’m sure this app has no connection to HTC, someone just uses that name to trick people into trusting it. So _don’t do it_, it would just be __plain stupid__.

Answer (score 0):

> i saw some sites that with that token can like pictures and post to anyone wall with it, without any login

This is not possible. The closest to this you'll get is a Like button widget or a link to the Facebook Share dialog - it's certainly not possible via the API, the abuse potential is obvious.